# Converting one collection to another in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Suppose we have an original collection (call it it source) with three documents like this

```
{ "_id" :ObjectId("54"), "f1" : "Josh", "f2" : 12 }
{ "_id" :ObjectId("53"), "f1" : "Ray", "f3" : 1971 }
{ "_id" :ObjectId("56"), "f1" : "Jim", "f2" : 17, "f3" : 5, "f4" : "Spri", "f5" :"hg" }
```

Now I want to create a new empty collection (call it dest) with same number of documents but with the following format

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501"), "f1" : "", "f2" :"", "f3"=""  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520"), "f1" : "", "f2" :"", "f3"=""  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("534"), "f1" : "", "f2" :"", "f3"=""  }
```

How do I update the new dest collection from the source collection? I need to find the matching fields for each record/document and update just these fields. do I have to go record by record using db.users.find().forEach? is there any trick?

Comment: What are you pulling from the original collection into the new collection?  They seem to have the same format and I don't see any common data.

Comment: I am replacing the data from source collection to the dest collection. that means the first record in dest collection after the update will be { "_id" : ObjectId("501"), "f1" : "Josh", "f2" :12, "f3"=""  }

Comment: I still don't understand the specifics of what you're trying to do, but if you want to generate a new collection based on the contents of an existing one, the typical approach is to use [map-reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/).

Comment: Thanks, all I want to do is to create a new collection such that each records in it has fixed number of fields (f1,f2,f3). Now I fill this collection from the original one record by record, if there is a field match, it updates it, if not the fields will be empty. I am new to this, the mapreduce one looks  bit complicated for this but if that is the only way I will try it. Thanks again

Comment: The _id value (ObjectId) in the new collection is different than in the old collection in your example.  How exactly are you "matching up" the source and destination if not by the _id?

Comment: also, how big is your source collection?

Comment: The source and destination collections have the same number of records(documents) so it is a one to one map, the destination is basically a clean up of the source collection. The source collection is also big, ( don;t know the exact size though